# Добавление файла в папку files при компиляции

Tags: android, файлы

Нужно, чтобы при создании apk файла к нему прицепилась ещё одна папка в папку files или куда-нибудь ещё, чтобы её можно было достать потом в процессе работы приложения. Создать её во время работы приложения просто невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Для хранения своих файлов используйте папку `app\src\main\res\raw` из которой и читайте нужные Вам файлы. Структура подпапок на Ваше усмотрения. Я например храню там json-файлы.

Comment: спасибо вам большое